# React: does not match the corresponding name on disk/ emotion

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

**error:**

```
./src/App.tsx
Cannot find file: 'emotion-react.browser.esm.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: 'C:\Users\gabrielti\Documents\emasa-management\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\Emasa-Management'.
```

I use a mono repo structure, which is as follows

packages / client

packages / server

Mono repo package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xemasa_monorepo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/sptGabriel/x-Management.git",
  "private":true,
  "workspaces":{
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ]
  },
  "author": "Gabriel Costa Cerqueira <Gabrielcerqueira96@hotmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "prepare-commit-msg": "exec < /dev/tty && git cz --hook || true",
      "commit-msg": "commitlint -E HUSKY_GIT_PARAMS"
    }
  }
}
```

Client package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@emasa_monorepo/client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.2",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/styled-system": "^5.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "class-validator": "^0.12.2",
    "history": "^5.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash.get": "^4.4.2",
    "mobx": "^6.0.4",
    "mobx-react-lite": "2.2.2",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^4.0.2",
    "polished": "^4.0.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-hamburger-menu": "^1.2.1",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "styled-system": "^5.1.5",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "type-check": "tsc --project tsconfig.json --pretty --noEmit",
    "lint": "eslint --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx --fix",
    "prettier-format": "prettier --config .prettierrc ./src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --write"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/lodash.get": "^4.4.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-hamburger-menu": "^0.0.3",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/universal-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators-legacy",
      "transform-class-properties"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-app",
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    {
      "runtime": "automatic",
      "importSource": "@emotion/react"
    }
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@emotion/babel-plugin",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      {
        "loose": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

app.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react'
import { useAppTheme } from './shared/utils/useAppTheme'
import GlobalReset from './shared/utils/cssReset'
const App: React.FC = observer(() => {
  const { theme } = useAppTheme()
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalReset />
      <div>a</div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
})

export default App
```

file: emotion-react.browser.esm.js exists on :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4GOM.png)

emotion-react.browser.esm.js code:

```
import { createElement, useContext, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import '@emotion/cache';
import { h as hasOwnProperty, E as Emotion, c as createEmotionProps, w as withEmotionCache, T as ThemeContext } from './emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js';
export { C as CacheProvider, T as ThemeContext, a as ThemeProvider, u as useTheme, w as withEmotionCache, b as withTheme } from './emotion-element-4fbd89c5.browser.esm.js';
import '@babel/runtime/helpers/extends';
import '@emotion/weak-memoize';
import 'hoist-non-react-statics';
import '../isolated-hoist-non-react-statics-do-not-use-this-in-your-code/dist/emotion-react-isolated-hoist-non-react-statics-do-not-use-this-in-your-code.browser.esm.js';
import { insertStyles, getRegisteredStyles } from '@emotion/utils';
import { serializeStyles } from '@emotion/serialize';
import { StyleSheet } from '@emotion/sheet';

var pkg = {
    name: "@emotion/react",
    version: "11.1.2",
    main: "dist/emotion-react.cjs.js",
    module: "dist/emotion-react.esm.js",
    browser: {
        "./dist/emotion-react.cjs.js": "./dist/emotion-react.browser.cjs.js",
        "./dist/emotion-react.esm.js": "./dist/emotion-react.browser.esm.js"
    },
    types: "types/index.d.ts",
    files: [
        "src",
        "dist",
        "jsx-runtime",
        "jsx-dev-runtime",
        "isolated-hoist-non-react-statics-do-not-use-this-in-your-code",
        "types/*.d.ts",
        "macro.js",
        "macro.d.ts",
        "macro.js.flow"
    ],
    sideEffects: false,
    author: "mitchellhamilton <mitchell@mitchellhamilton.me>",
    license: "MIT",
    scripts: {
        "test:typescript": "dtslint types"
    },
    dependencies: {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.7.2",
        "@emotion/cache": "^11.0.0",
        "@emotion/serialize": "^1.0.0",
        "@emotion/sheet": "^1.0.1",
        "@emotion/utils": "^1.0.0",
        "@emotion/weak-memoize": "^0.2.5",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.1"
    },
    peerDependencies: {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        react: ">=16.8.0"
    },
    peerDependenciesMeta: {
        "@babel/core": {
            optional: true
        },
        "@types/react": {
            optional: true
        }
    },
    devDependencies: {
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.2",
        "@emotion/css": "11.0.0",
        "@emotion/css-prettifier": "1.0.0",
        "@emotion/server": "11.0.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "11.0.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.11",
        dtslint: "^0.3.0",
        "html-tag-names": "^1.1.2",
        react: "16.14.0",
        "svg-tag-names": "^1.1.1"
    },
    repository: "https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/tree/master/packages/react",
    publishConfig: {
        access: "public"
    },
    "umd:main": "dist/emotion-react.umd.min.js",
    preconstruct: {
        entrypoints: [
            "./index.js",
            "./jsx-runtime.js",
            "./jsx-dev-runtime.js",
            "./isolated-hoist-non-react-statics-do-not-use-this-in-your-code.js"
        ],
        umdName: "emotionReact"
    }
};

var jsx = function jsx(type, props) {
  var args = arguments;

  if (props == null || !hasOwnProperty.call(props, 'css')) {
    // $FlowFixMe
    return createElement.apply(undefined, args);
  }

  var argsLength = args.length;
  var createElementArgArray = new Array(argsLength);
  createElementArgArray[0] = Emotion;
  createElementArgArray[1] = createEmotionProps(type, props);

  for (var i = 2; i < argsLength; i++) {
    createElementArgArray[i] = args[i];
  } // $FlowFixMe


  return createElement.apply(null, createElementArgArray);
};

var warnedAboutCssPropForGlobal = false; // maintain place over rerenders.
// initial render from browser, insertBefore context.sheet.tags[0] or if a style hasn't been inserted there yet, appendChild
// initial client-side render from SSR, use place of hydrating tag

var Global = /* #__PURE__ */withEmotionCache(function (props, cache) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && !warnedAboutCssPropForGlobal && ( // check for className as well since the user is
  // probably using the custom createElement which
  // means it will be turned into a className prop
  // $FlowFixMe I don't really want to add it to the type since it shouldn't be used
  props.className || props.css)) {
    console.error("It looks like you're using the css prop on Global, did you mean to use the styles prop instead?");
    warnedAboutCssPropForGlobal = true;
  }

  var styles = props.styles;
  var serialized = serializeStyles([styles], undefined, typeof styles === 'function' || Array.isArray(styles) ? useContext(ThemeContext) : undefined);
  // but it is based on a constant that will never change at runtime
  // it's effectively like having two implementations and switching them out
  // so it's not actually breaking anything


  var sheetRef = useRef();
  useLayoutEffect(function () {
    var key = cache.key + "-global";
    var sheet = new StyleSheet({
      key: key,
      nonce: cache.sheet.nonce,
      container: cache.sheet.container,
      speedy: cache.sheet.isSpeedy
    }); // $FlowFixMe

    var node = document.querySelector("style[data-emotion=\"" + key + " " + serialized.name + "\"]");

    if (cache.sheet.tags.length) {
      sheet.before = cache.sheet.tags[0];
    }

    if (node !== null) {
      sheet.hydrate([node]);
    }

    sheetRef.current = sheet;
    return function () {
      sheet.flush();
    };
  }, [cache]);
  useLayoutEffect(function () {
    if (serialized.next !== undefined) {
      // insert keyframes
      insertStyles(cache, serialized.next, true);
    }

    var sheet = sheetRef.current;

    if (sheet.tags.length) {
      // if this doesn't exist then it will be null so the style element will be appended
      var element = sheet.tags[sheet.tags.length - 1].nextElementSibling;
      sheet.before = element;
      sheet.flush();
    }

    cache.insert("", serialized, sheet, false);
  }, [cache, serialized.name]);
  return null;
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  Global.displayName = 'EmotionGlobal';
}

function css() {
  for (var _len = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
    args[_key] = arguments[_key];
  }

  return serializeStyles(args);
}

var keyframes = function keyframes() {
  var insertable = css.apply(void 0, arguments);
  var name = "animation-" + insertable.name; // $FlowFixMe

  return {
    name: name,
    styles: "@keyframes " + name + "{" + insertable.styles + "}",
    anim: 1,
    toString: function toString() {
      return "_EMO_" + this.name + "_" + this.styles + "_EMO_";
    }
  };
};

var classnames = function classnames(args) {
  var len = args.length;
  var i = 0;
  var cls = '';

  for (; i < len; i++) {
    var arg = args[i];
    if (arg == null) continue;
    var toAdd = void 0;

    switch (typeof arg) {
      case 'boolean':
        break;

      case 'object':
        {
          if (Array.isArray(arg)) {
            toAdd = classnames(arg);
          } else {
            if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && arg.styles !== undefined && arg.name !== undefined) {
              console.error('You have passed styles created with `css` from `@emotion/react` package to the `cx`.\n' + '`cx` is meant to compose class names (strings) so you should convert those styles to a class name by passing them to the `css` received from <ClassNames/> component.');
            }

            toAdd = '';

            for (var k in arg) {
              if (arg[k] && k) {
                toAdd && (toAdd += ' ');
                toAdd += k;
              }
            }
          }

          break;
        }

      default:
        {
          toAdd = arg;
        }
    }

    if (toAdd) {
      cls && (cls += ' ');
      cls += toAdd;
    }
  }

  return cls;
};

function merge(registered, css, className) {
  var registeredStyles = [];
  var rawClassName = getRegisteredStyles(registered, registeredStyles, className);

  if (registeredStyles.length < 2) {
    return className;
  }

  return rawClassName + css(registeredStyles);
}

var ClassNames = /* #__PURE__ */withEmotionCache(function (props, cache) {
  var hasRendered = false;

  var css = function css() {
    if (hasRendered && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      throw new Error('css can only be used during render');
    }

    for (var _len = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len), _key = 0; _key < _len; _key++) {
      args[_key] = arguments[_key];
    }

    var serialized = serializeStyles(args, cache.registered);

    {
      insertStyles(cache, serialized, false);
    }

    return cache.key + "-" + serialized.name;
  };

  var cx = function cx() {
    if (hasRendered && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      throw new Error('cx can only be used during render');
    }

    for (var _len2 = arguments.length, args = new Array(_len2), _key2 = 0; _key2 < _len2; _key2++) {
      args[_key2] = arguments[_key2];
    }

    return merge(cache.registered, css, classnames(args));
  };

  var content = {
    css: css,
    cx: cx,
    theme: useContext(ThemeContext)
  };
  var ele = props.children(content);
  hasRendered = true;

  return ele;
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  ClassNames.displayName = 'EmotionClassNames';
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  var isBrowser = "object" !== 'undefined'; // #1727 for some reason Jest evaluates modules twice if some consuming module gets mocked with jest.mock

  var isJest = typeof jest !== 'undefined';

  if (isBrowser && !isJest) {
    var globalContext = isBrowser ? window : global;
    var globalKey = "__EMOTION_REACT_" + pkg.version.split('.')[0] + "__";

    if (globalContext[globalKey]) {
      console.warn('You are loading @emotion/react when it is already loaded. Running ' + 'multiple instances may cause problems. This can happen if multiple ' + 'versions are used, or if multiple builds of the same version are ' + 'used.');
    }

    globalContext[globalKey] = true;
  }
}

export { ClassNames, Global, jsx as createElement, css, jsx, keyframes };
```

I already searched and found nothing about it, I don't know what's going on